# $L^1_{\mu}$ as limit

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, ct.category-theory, measure-theory, limits-and-colimits

Let $(X,\Sigma,\mu)$ be a $\sigma$-finite measure space.  Does there exist a countable set of finite measures $\{\mu_n\}_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ on $(X,\Sigma)$ such that $L^1_{\mu}(\Sigma)$ can be written as the projective-limit in the category of LCS
$$
L^1_{\mu}(\Sigma) = \projlim\, L^1_{\mu_n}(\Sigma),
$$
for some suitable restriction maps $\pi_n^m:L^1_{\mu_m}(\Sigma) \rightarrow L^1_{\mu_n}(\Sigma)$.

*Related*: [Can $L^1_{loc}$ be represented as colimit?](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/347318/can-l1-loc-be-represented-as-colimit?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Comment: Taking projective limits of Banach spaces in the sense of lcs’s will not usually produce a Banach space, as pointed out below. However, the category of Banach spaces with contractions  as morphisms does have projective limits and I would suggest that this might be what you want. As a simple example, if $\mu$ is Lebesgue measure on the line, and $\mu_n$ is its restriction to $[-n,n]$, the sequence $(L^1(\mu_m))$ has the corresponding $L^1$-space as projective limit in the second sense, but $L^1_{loc}$, the Fréchet space of locally integrable functions, in the first.

Comment: This is very interesting actually.  Could you possibly provide a reference to this; maybe some book?

Comment: I can‘t think of one for this explicit situation but both follow directly from the general construction of such projective limits as compatible threads, in this case as compatible sequences $(f_n)$ with $f_n \in L^1(\mu_n)$.  In the lcs case  there is no growth condition so they combine to form  a locally integrable function, in the Banach space one, the $L^1$ norms are bounded so you get a globally $L^1$ function.

Comment: @user131781 would you happen to have a reference on $L^1$ described this way in the Category of Banach spaces and (linear?) contractions?

Comment: Well, no but it is so elementary that I don‘t think that one needs a reference. It is simply the fact that if you have a compatible, bounded sequence $(f_n)$ where $f_n$ is in $L^1([-n,n])$, then they combine to form an integrable function on the line.  The only possible finesse comes from the fact that the functions are only defined a.e. but the countability condition takes care of that.  Of course, I only chose the real line as an example—-this works for any $\sigma$-finite meaure.  A useful toy example to make everything transparent would be the positive integers with counting measure.

Comment: Perfect!  I'll work this out then; thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is a strictly positive integrable function $f\in L^1_\mu(\Sigma)$, hence $\nu=f\cdot \mu$ is a finite measure and $\Phi:L^1_\nu(\Sigma)\to L^1_\mu(\Sigma)$, $g\mapsto gf$ is an isomorphism. In particular, $L^1_\mu(\Sigma)$ is *isomorphic* to a projective limit of $L^1_{\mu_n}(\Sigma)$ with finite measures (and if you define a projective limit in the categorial sense by universal properties *isomorphic to* and *equal to* a projective limit is the same).

Let me add a general remark: Projective limits in the category of locally convex spaces are extremely useful to represent general spaces by simpler ones, in particular Frechet spaces as countable projective limits of Banach spaces. Useful results usually require an additional property called *reducedness*, i.e., the connecting maps $\pi_m^n:X_m\to X_n$ have dense range for $m\ge n$ or variants of that, like the *Mittag-Leffler condition* for all $n$ there is $m\ge n$ such that for all $k\ge m$ we have $\pi_m^n(X_m)\subseteq \overline{\pi_k^n(X_k)}$, the abstract Mittag-Leffler theorem then implies that this also holds for $k=\infty$ where $\pi_\infty^n$ is the map from the projective limit into the $n$th step. Your question asks for a representation of a Banach space by other Banach spaces which is somewhat queer to the theory because the limit of a *reduced* spectrum of Banach spaces is again a Banach space only if for all but finitely many $n$ the linking maps $\pi_m^n$ are isomorphisms.

Comment: Thank you, I'll definitely keep the Mittag-Leffler condition in mind; I think it will be useful for my applications.  Would you happen to have a recommendation on the subject?

Comment: My Springer Lecture Note "Derived Functors in Functional Analysis" contain some information about that.

Comment: Thank you very much for the reference I'm looking at it now.  However, now I'm curious about the dual question; namely, can $L^1_{\mu}$ be represented as a colimit of $L^1_{\mu_n}(\Sigma)$ spaces for aptly chosen $\mu_n$?

Comment: As it is isomorphic to such a space it is isomorphic to a (trivial) colimit.