# Sobolev topology on essentially compactly supported Sobolev-"functions"

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, ap.analysis-of-pdes, sobolev-spaces, limits-and-colimits, topological-vector-spaces

The locally convex space of *essentially compactly-supported $p$-integrable "functions"* $\operatorname{L}_{\mathrm{comp}}^p(\mathbb{R}^d,\mathbb{R})$ is defined as the set
$$
\bigcup_{n \in \mathbb{N}} \left\{
f \in L^p(\mathbb{R}^d,\mathbb{R}):\, \operatorname{ess-supp}(f)\subseteq [-n,n]^d
\right\},
$$
topologized with the [injective limit topology](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Final_topology) in the category of [LCSs](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/locally+convex+topological+vector+space) with continuous linear maps as morphisms, where the colimit is taken over the [injective system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Direct_limit) $$\left\{L^p(\mathbb{R}^d,\mathbb{R}):\, \operatorname{ess-supp}(f)\subseteq [-n,n]^d\right\}_{n \in \mathbb{N}}.$$

Fix a $k \in \mathbb{N}$, $1\leq p<\infty$ and let $W^{k,p}_{\mathrm{comp}}(\mathbb{R}^d):=W^{k,p}(\mathbb{R}^d) \cap \operatorname{L}_{\mathrm{comp}}^p$.  How are the subspace topologies on $W^{k,p}_{\mathrm{comp}}(\mathbb{R}^d)$ comparable?  Is the subspace topology induced by restricting the subspace topology on $L^p_{\mathrm{comp}}(\mathbb{R}^d,\mathbb{R})$ to $W^{k,p}_{\mathrm{comp}}(\mathbb{R}^d)$ at-least as fine than the one obtained by restricting the Sobolev topology $W^{k,p}$ to $W^{k,p}_{\mathrm{comp}}(\mathbb{R}^d)$?

Comment: Why should this be true? The $L^p_{comp}$-topology gives nothing for the distributional derivatives! You probably know that because of the stricness of the inductive system the relative topology of $L^p_{comp}$ on the steps is just the $L^p$-topology.

Comment: But in this post:
https://mathoverflow.net/questions/347318/can-l1-loc-be-represented-as-colimit?noredirect=1&lq=1

don't we find that the topology on $L^p_{comp}$ is strictly finer?

Comment: Indeed, the $L^p_{comp}$ topology is stricly finer than the $L^p$-topology, but on the steps they coincide. There is no contradiction.

Comment: Oh my brain filtered the word "steps" sorry.  I've never seen this terminology, you mean the finite "sub-colimits?".  In that case definitely.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To make my comment an answer: No. To see this, fix a cube $K$ and look at $L^p_K=\{f\in L^p: \text{ ess-supp}(f) \subseteq K\}$. On this space, the $L^p_{comp}$-topology coincides with the $L^p$-topology (this follows from the stricness of the inductive limit) and the $W^{k,p}$-topology is strictly finer on this subspace.

Comment: Ah, you're right this is very clear.